# Bounds on sum of cosines

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation, exponential-sum

Find bound on the following sums for $k\in \{1,\dots p-1\}$ where $p$ is a prime (even assumed to be $3\mod 4$, I used this to get to the current sum) find good upper and lower bounds on

$$\sum_{s=0}^{\sqrt{p}}1-\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi }{p}ks^{2} \right)$$

Here I tried to use a Taylor expansion of various degrees and I end up having to sum over consecutive integers power of order $4,8$ and I was wondering was there another simple ways of getting bounds?

Comment: $\sqrt{p}$ is not an integer. How is it the upper limit of your sum?

Comment: Well you sum over integers up to $\sqrt{p}$ so in this case the upper bound would be $\lfloor \sqrt p\rfloor$.

Comment: Well the sum is over $s$ so $s^2$ is just the square of $s$.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a finite sum over consecutive integer powers of 4 or 8, then there is a closed form and wolfram can definitely help. Sorry to comment in the answer, my account is not rich enough to comment yet.

Comment: Yes that is true but depending on the order of $\sqrt{p}$ the bound may will be very poor if $\sqrt{p}$ is large. The order of the expansion of the Taylor polynomial should depend on the magnitude of $p$.

Comment: But you can always transit it to an angle between -$\pi$ and $\pi$

Comment: That is true by for an arbitrary $k$ how do you know for a given $s$ what $m$ do you pick so that $-\pi\leq \dfrac{2\pi}{p}ks^{2}-m\pi\leq \pi$. So you can get an actual estimate that you can compute.

Comment: Rearrange and use a floor function so you get a expression for $m$.